# bootstrap 3 datepicker, как сравнить 2 даты

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

Есть 2 календаря от bootstrap 3, нужно чтобы при выборе 2 дат, было выбрано не меньше 3 дней, при первом старте как вывеси получилось, а вот при изменении не понятно. То есть если менять поля "С" или "По" должна быть проверка если диапазон дат меньше 3 то выставлять 3 даты минимально, а если пользователь выбрал больше то ставить то что выбрал. Нужно как бы запретить пользователю выбрать диапазон меньше чем 3 дня.

```js
$(function () {                
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
   minDate: moment(),
    defaultDate: moment(),
    format: 'DD.MM.YY'
  });

  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
   format: 'DD.MM.YY',
   minDate: moment().add(3, 'days'),
    defaultDate: moment().add(3, 'days'),
    useCurrent: false
  });

  $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date.add(3, 'days'));    
  
  });      

  $("#datetimepicker2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>



<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' >
                    С <input id='datetimepicker1' type='text' class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class='input-group date'>
                    По <input id='datetimepicker2' type='text' class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Решил сам))) через moment.js

```js
$(function () {                
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
   minDate: moment(),
    defaultDate: moment(),
    format: 'DD.MM.YY'
  });

  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
   format: 'DD.MM.YY',
   minDate: moment().add(3, 'days'),
    defaultDate: moment().add(3, 'days'),
    useCurrent: false
  });

  $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) { 
    $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date.add(3, 'days')); 
    if(moment(e.date).isAfter($('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").date())){
      $ ('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>



<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' >
                    С <input id='datetimepicker1' type='text' class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class='input-group date'>
                    По <input id='datetimepicker2' type='text' class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```